# Which programming mistakes make Debug run faster than release?(How can debug run faster than release?)

Tags: c++, performance, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

İ am trying to create basic memory system,What i see its works.I am doing stress test and look for ratio against malloc,My problem is in Debug mode my ratio is 12-13 but in release mode its down to 5.8-6 i dont understand the what is the reason.I know in release mode not initilazion variables consume time but i think i initalize all my variables.My warning lvl is 4. İf my code is slow how can it run faster in debug mode than release which should be faster? There are probaly some mistakes in my code but i am not sure what couse of it.

***ratio in Release :***
     Mem Lib: stress test: 3471.899902 ms
     Custom Memory: stress test: 592.518250 ms
     **times faster: 5.859566**
***ratio in Debug***
      Mem Lib: stress test: 5603.395996 ms
      Custom Memory: stress test: 436.663391 ms
       **times faster: 12.832301**

As you can see My custom memory time is increased(more than debug mode) In debug it took **436** sec but in Release its **592**  this is my problem.
I am using Visual Studio 12

Here is my Free code:

```
memVoid memSystem::Free( memVoid * const p ){

usedHdr * pUsed= (usedHdr *)p;
pUsed--;
heapHdr *pHeap = this->getHeap();

//Delete Used
if(pHeap->usedHead->usedNext!=0)
{
    if(pUsed->usedPrev==0)
    {
      pHeap->usedHead= pUsed->usedNext;
      pHeap->usedHead->usedPrev=0;
    }
    else if(pUsed->usedNext==0)
    {
        pUsed->usedPrev->usedNext=0;

    }
    else{
        pUsed->usedNext->usedPrev=pUsed->usedPrev;
        pUsed->usedPrev->usedNext=pUsed->usedNext;}
}
else
pHeap->usedHead=0;

freeHdr *pFree= (freeHdr*) pUsed;
memStats  *pStats =&pHeap->stats;


///p free 
pFree->blockSize = pUsed->blockSize;
pFree->freeNext=0;
pFree->freePrev=0;
pFree->blockType=FREE_TYPE;
pFree->pad0=0;
pFree->pad1=0;
pFree->pad2=0;
pStats->currUsedMem-=pFree->blockSize;
///Insert Free to list as Sorted
InsertSorted(pFree);

pStats->currNumFreeBlocks++;
pStats->currFreeMem+=pFree->blockSize;
//////This for collapsing(union) two freen eighbors
///Look for up
freeHdr*  pFreelist=pFree->freePrev;
if(pFreelist!=0)
{
    memU32 i= memU32(pFreelist)+pFreelist->blockSize+sizeof(freeHdr);
    if(i==(memU32)pFree)
    {
        pFreelist->freeNext=pFree->freeNext;
        if(pFree->freeNext!=0)
        pFree->freeNext->freePrev=pFreelist;

        pFreelist->blockSize+=pFree->blockSize+sizeof(freeHdr);
        pStats->currNumFreeBlocks--;
        pStats->currFreeMem+=sizeof(freeHdr);
        pFree=pFreelist;
    }

}
///Look For Down
pFreelist=pFree->freeNext;
if(pFreelist!=0)
{
    memU32 i= memU32(pFree)+pFree->blockSize+sizeof(freeHdr);
    if(i==(memU32)pFreelist)
    {
        pFree->freeNext=pFreelist->freeNext;

        if(pFreelist->freeNext!=0)
        pFreelist->freeNext->freePrev=pFree;
        else
            pFree->freeNext=0;

        pFree->blockSize+=pFreelist->blockSize+sizeof(freeHdr);
        pStats->currNumFreeBlocks--;
        pStats->currFreeMem+=sizeof(freeHdr);
    }

}pStats->currNumUsedBlocks--;}
```

Comment: how are you profiling this? And since you have classes this is definitely not C

Comment: actually they are all structs.Sory

Comment: The syntax `memSystem::Free` doesn't make sense in C and in C++ `class` and `struct` are nearly the same.

Comment: Could you take the time to properly indent your code? Also, VS2012 has a nice profiler, run your program through it and see which parts of your code take longer in Debug than in Release mode.

Comment: Proper benchmarking is a fine art that's *way* too easy to fumble.  No hints at all in the question.  The standard trap is overlooking the *true* cost of using memory on a demand-paged virtual memory operating system like Windows.  Allocating is very cheap, just numbers to the processor, it is *accessing* the memory that's expensive.  That produces page faults, forcing the virtual memory page to get mapped into RAM.  The standard trap in a Debug build is having the debug heap enabled.  Which initializes memory early, thus taking those page faults early.